# Экранная клавиатура android

Tags: android, клавиатура

В ландшафтном режиме на некоторых устройствах при открытии клавиатуры над ней остается видно часть формы, а на других появляется большое окно ввода. При этом в какое поле вводим текст, не видно. Как сделать, чтобы над клавиатурой всегда была видна часть формы? Куда копать?

Comment: Посмотрите вот [это][1].
Это решение не подойдет?

  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/350330/android-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-textfield-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: Не помогло ((

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Добавьте к вашему EditText такой атрибут в XML

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```

Вообще ответ найден в [гугле](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20edittext%20landscape%20full%20screen&es_th=1) за 36 секунд.

Comment: О спасибо!!! А я так и не смог найти, наверное, потому что не знал, что искать.